# Two projects in one repository with GitHub Actions (monorepo)

Tags: github, github-actions, monorepo

I am currently working on my personal e-commerce project that I am developing with Java/spring boot for the backend and angular for the frontend. Both projects (frontend and backend) are in a single repository on GitHub.

How can I set up single GitHub workflow for both projects ?

[Screenshot of my project's repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uzt0v.png)

Comment: Have you tried "reusable workflows"?

Comment: I have, but didn't work. I've separated the projects into two different repos. It's easier like that. Thank you for your answer and time.

Comment: I'd be interested to know how that didn't work. Perhaps open a new question about that?

Comment: It only worked for one project in particular. I researched again and found out that I had to use the "working directory" option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since most actions assume your code is in the root of the project and the `working-directory` option [doesn't work on job level](https://github.community/t/use-working-directory-for-entire-job/16747) you can do a little trick.

Assuming you have a directory structure like:

```
backend/
 - gradlew.sh
 - src/
frontend/
 - package.json
 - src
```

You can:

- create one job for the backend and one for the frontend
- move the subfolders to the root at the beginning of the job
- run commands/actions

This is what this could look like:

```yaml
jobs:
  be:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - run: mv -f backend/* .
      - uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: 17
          distribution: temurin
      - run: ./gradlew check
  fe:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - run: mv -f frontend/* .
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16
      - run: npm build && npm test
```

Be careful though: This `mv` just moves all contents from the subfolder into the root. If you have some other files in the root that might interfere, you should first clean the root by deleting all files and directories but the `backend` directory.

Comment: I finally did. With your help of course. Thank you for your answers and your time.