# Setting up GH actions in a subdirectory (several packages in one repo)

Tags: r, package, repository, github-actions, r-usethis

When writing R packages, I prefer to set up CI with `usethis::use_github_actions()`, which creates a `.github/` directory in the root, where GH action jobs are designed to run: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72268873/8400969.
I have a legacy repo that contains several R packages in a `/R` directory, and some other things (e.g., a python application) in other directories, and would like to set up continuous integration for the R packages (each, separately, ideally without moving each to their own repo).
How can I set up the GH actions workflows so they check each R package in the `/R` parent directory, separately? Will I be able to use the tools from **usethis** to create badges, pkgdown websites, etc. with a repo structure like this?

Hard to know what a reproducible example is, but maybe this is a good starting point: a directory with two mature R packages in them, each (currently) with their own `.github` subdirectory providing instructions for GH actions.

Commands entered into shell on macOS to create:

```
mkdir example_repo
cd example_repo
git clone https://github.com/r-lib/scales.git
git clone https://github.com/r-lib/roxygen2
cd roxygen2
rm -rf .git
cd ../scales
rm -rf .git
```

Comment: This looks potentially helpful: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestpull_request_targetpathspaths-ignore
Even if `working-directory` won't get me there, maybe `paths` will?

Comment: If I understand correctly, `paths` is more about what triggers the action than where it takes place.